# Prove that $\int\limits_{-a}^{a}f(x)dx = 2 \int\limits_{0}^{a}f(x)dx$ if function $f(x)$ is even

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, functions, definite-integrals

Prove that $\int\limits_{-a}^{a}f(x)dx = 2 \int\limits_{0}^{a}f(x)dx$ if functio is even.

$\int\limits_{-a}^{a}f(x)dx = \int\limits_{-a}^{0}f(x)dx + \int\limits_{0}^{a}f(x)dx$

$\int\limits_{-a}^{0}f(x)dx =$ |substitution $-u = x, -du = dx$, since $u = -x$, lower limit becomes u = a| = $\int\limits_{a}^{0}f(-u)(-du) = -\int\limits_{a}^{0}f(-u)du = -\int\limits_{a}^{0}f(u)du = \int\limits_{0}^{a}f(u)du$ = |now return $u=-x$ and $du=-dx$| = $\int\limits_{0}^{a}f(-x)(-dx) = -\int\limits_{0}^{a}f(-x)dx = -\int\limits_{0}^{a}f(x)dx$

But this is wrong and I wouln't get the right answer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: After you get $\int_{0}^{a}f(u)du$, you don't want to substitute back for u.  Instead, use that u is a dummy variable.

Comment: @user84413 Why can I use dummy variable? I have searched about it, but I can't find the proof. If I used the substitution method, shouldn't then I substitue $x$ back like I do when solving integrals?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\int_{0}^{a} f(u)du = \int_{0}^{a} f(x)dx$. Because independs on the variable. Search on [dummy variables](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DummyVariable.html).

Comment: Could you please explain why can I do that? I have searched for, but can't find any reasonbly simple proof.

Comment: Sure, once you have a definite interal the variable turns out to be a symbol, evaluate $\int_{0}^{1} x^2 dx$ and $\int_{0}^{1} t^2 dt$. You have a number that independs of the chosen variable.